# node-gyp Debug|Release configuration variable

Tags: node.js, gyp

is there a way, how to tell if the configuration is set to Debug or Release inside of a bindings.gyp?

For example in Visual Studio there is a variable $(Configuration), which contains this information. Does something similar exist in gyp?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

node's own `common.gypi` [contains an example](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/f39e608c6eb11c91839ea4661caece1f89f1b12f/common.gypi) of how to configure things differently depending on the build configuration.